# put command line arguments for tests in cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a way to write command line arguments for tests (exitcode-stdio-1.0) in the cabal file?

I can run the tests manually with

```
cabal test --test-options="foo bar"
```

but I don't want to (re-)type this.

Comment: If there isn't a way to do it with Cabal, you could always just write a shell script... (Although obviously that only works for your dev box.)

Comment: Yes. -- I could understand if cabal designers refused to do this on the grounds that your tests should be (completely) specified in the (Haskell) source (for repeatability). But then why did they implement `--test-options`? So my question is, whether the design is inconsistent (`--test-options` allowed on command line, but forbidden in cabal file) or I am simply missing something.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this. As the comments suggest, if there are default options for the test-suite, they should just be baked into the executable. Command line options are intended only for *overriding or modifying* those default options. There is no way to add additional options in the cabal file