# Cabal testsuite - How can I pass a flag?

Tags: haskell, cabal, htf

I use cabal with test-suites. The processor I use (HTF) allows flags (e.g. `--quiet`). How can I add such flags in the cabal file in order to be passed automatically to the test suite program when it is executed?

Comment: TBH: I don't know (if there even is one) - but in this case why don't you make this a default in your implementation (using [`htfMainWithArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF-0.13.1.0/docs/Test-Framework.html#v:htfMainWithArgs))? - look for the args in your main, if none are there pass your default ... yes it's a hack and maybe someone knows the correct flag but till then it should work for you

Comment: also I think this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902169/put-command-line-arguments-for-tests-in-cabal-file

Comment: great idea - did work immediately! `htfMainWithArgs ["--quiet"] htf_importedTests` does the trick!

Comment: @Cartsen since your comment provided an answer, care to post it as one?