# haskell automated test configuration

Tags: unit-testing, haskell

I have set up a project and I want to write tests for it. Now the problem is my functions in production work with a database but in tests I want to direct them towards a fake database.

for example I have the string `mongoHostAdress = "192.168.0.1"` which my functions use to access mongo database, and I when testing I want it to change to `mongoHostAdress = "127.0.0.1"`.

how can I tell Haskell to automatically do this for me ?

**Edit : more general outlook**

how can I create a config file for a project and use different params for different stages of the project?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better not to hardcode the address and store it in an environment variable instead, with different values in testing and production. Part III of the twelve-factor app Manifesto: https://12factor.net/config

Comment: @danidiaz that is exacly what I want. how can I instruct the ghc to read some options from a let's say yaml file and use it accordingly ?
Is a yaml file standard in haskell ? you know, these kind of stuff I don't know.

Comment: The `aeson` package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson can be used to parse JSON. The `yaml` package uses the same in-memory representation as `aeson` and can read YAML files http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.21.2/docs/Data-Yaml.html#v:decodeFile. You can also import `System.Environment` to read environment variables. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html See also the `configurator-ng` package https://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator-ng

Comment: @danidiaz ok, I can read the config, how can I apply them? I run my tests with 'cabal test'. how can I tell the program to use a different config when it is a test ?

Comment: According to `cabal test --help`, you can use `--test-option` to pass arguments to the test executable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902169/put-command-line-arguments-for-tests-in-cabal-file which you can then read using `getArgs` from `System.Environment`. The alternative `stack` tool will have similar options. I usually just use environment variables that I set using a wrapper .sh script, or from the command line itself.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I need more info on this. I could not find anything useful on the internet and I don't want to re-invent the wheel. surely there are well-stablished methods and detailed description on how to use them!

Comment: As an example, look at this test suite for a project of mine: https://github.com/danidiaz/users-mysql-haskell/tree/master/tests and the wrapper `.sh` file https://github.com/danidiaz/users-mysql-haskell/blob/master/tests.sh The configuration is passed through environment variables here.

Comment: OK, will look into it. thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134297/discussion-between-milad-zahedi-and-danidiaz).

Answer (score 3):

So the concept is create file input.txt which looks like this:

```
fstParameterName:fstParameterValue
sndParameterName:sndParameterValue
trdParameterName:trdParameterValue
```

Now inside main function you can easily set your params using construction like this:

```
main = do
text <- readFile "input.txt"
mongoHostAdress <- (getConfigValue "mongoHostAdress" (lines text))
print(mongoHostAdress)

getConfigValue name (l:ls) = if(containsPrefix name l) 
  then (return(skipPrefix name l))
  else (getConfigValue name ls)

containsPrefix [] x = True
containsPrefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = if(x==y) then (containsPrefix xs ys) else False

skipPrefix [] (x:xs) = xs --x is just ":" and ofc we dont want it
skipPrefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = skipPrefix xs ys
```

Comment: one thing remains, how to make these configs available every where ?

Comment: You can read all data in main function and then just run functions that you're using in your program with additional params. Is it a good solution for you?

Comment: not possible, I want these configs to be availabe every where for all functions and tests, I cannot run them all from the main.